Issues Configuring Internationalization (i18n) in Angular 19
I am working on an Angular 19 project, and I'm trying to add internationalization (i18n) features to support multiple languages. I've followed several guides and suggestions, but I keep running into issues.
Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Installed the necessary package:
npm install @angular/localize --legacy-peer-deps

Updated my tsconfig.json:


  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022"
  },
  "files": [
    "node_modules/@angular/localize/init"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}


Updated my angular.json:

{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "YourProjectName": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/your-project-name",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/azure-blue.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kB",
                  "maximumError": "1MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "4kB",
                  "maximumError": "8kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            },
            "en": {
              "localize": ["en"],
              "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.xlf",
              "i18nLocale": "en",
              "outputPath": "dist/your-project-name/en",
              "aot": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "fr": {
              "localize": ["fr"],
              "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.fr.xlf",
              "i18nLocale": "fr",
              "outputPath": "dist/your-project-name/fr",
              "aot": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "port": 4200,
            "browserTarget": "YourProjectName:build:development"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "YourProjectName:build:production"
            },
            "en": {
              "browserTarget": "YourProjectName:build:en"
            },
            "fr": {
              "browserTarget": "YourProjectName:build:fr"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "YourProjectName:build"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Created translation files in src/locale:


messages.xlf for English
messages.fr.xlf for French

Issues Encountered:
When trying to serve the application for specific locales using:
ng serve --configuration=fr
ng serve --configuration=en

I encounter the following error:
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" must have required property 'buildTarget'.
/Users/ali/angular-applications/YourProjectName/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/util/reportUnhandledError.js:13
            throw err;
            ^

SchemaValidationException [Error]: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" must have required property 'buildTarget'.
    at /Users/ali/angular-applications/YourProjectName/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect.js:38:27 {
  errors: [
    {
      instancePath: '',
      schemaPath: '#/required',
      keyword: 'required',
      params: { missingProperty: 'buildTarget' },
      message: "must have required property 'buildTarget'"
    }
  ]
}

Questions:

How can I properly configure angular.json to support multiple locales without encountering the buildTarget error?

Are there any other steps I might have missed in setting up Angular i18n?


Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Could you replace all instance of browserTarget to buildTarget.
Below is a sample angular.json (ssr enabled) for reference:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "test": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/test",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "src/server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kB",
                  "maximumError": "1MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "4kB",
                  "maximumError": "8kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "test:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "test:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Hi @naren Muraili: I replaced all instances of browserTarget with buildTarget
then ng build --localize which gave me no error. then ng serve --configuration=fr which gave me following error
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(i18nFile).
errors: [ { instancePath: '', schemaPath: '#/additionalProperties', keyword: 'additionalProperties', params: { additionalProperty: 'i18nFile' }, message: 'must NOT have additional properties' } ]
